# Setting the default browser to open flex apps in Flash Builder on Mac?

Tags: actionscript-3, macos, flash-builder

I just got my MacBook and am trying out the Flash BUilder on said platform. I've installed Firefox and Google Chrome on my MacBook but I can't seem to find a way to set which browser would launch my Flex apps whenever I hit the Run button inside Flash Builder. As far as I know, I can locate the Browser property on the Project Properties on my Windows copy of Flash Builder but I couldn't over here at my Mac. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the browser associated with Flash Builder in the Flash Builder preferences window. It's under General -> Web Browser. This sets the default web browser for all items launched from FB I believe. I don't know of a method for doing this on a per-project basis, but this should solve your immediate problem. This is on FB 4.5, by the way, but I believe it's the same for previous versions as well.

Comment: Thank you! I was pretty sure it wasn't there before but when I checked it now, it was there. I must have been looking on the wrong place.